# Wordpress's Rest Api is fetching HTML Code

Tags: html, wordpress

I am using wordpress rest api to fetch products. But in the rest api, html code is passing too. Snapshot :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/APM0y.png

I used the following code, so rest api would not fetch the html code. But it does not work.

```
// Remove Span Tags From Woocommerce Price Start Here

function modify_wc_price( $return, $price, $args ) {
// remove span tags
$negative          = $price < 0;
$formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $args['price_format'],     get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $args['currency'] ), $price );
return $formatted_price;
}
  add_filter( 'wc_price', 'modify_wc_price', 99, 3 );

// Remove Span Tags From Woocommerce Price End Here
```

Could anyone let me know how can I solve the problem?